# If $P$ is an invertible linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field, then there is some $n>0$ such that $P^n=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, finite-fields

From *Berkeley problems in Mathematics*:

> problem 7.4.21: let $P$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field. show that if $P$ is invertible, then $P^n$ = $I$ for some positive integer $n$.

I think there is a mistake in the above statement: it does not hold true if P is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

But is the statement correct otherwise? i.e. is the following modified statement correct?

let $P$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field. assume $P$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity operator. show that if $P$ is invertible, then $P^n$ = $I$ for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: The statement certainly holds for $P=aI$ because $a^{n-1}=1$ if $a\ne0$ and the finite field has $n$ elements.

Comment: @lhf thanks! I had difficulty understanding the notion of a finite field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true even if $P$ is a scalar operator. Note that the field of scalars in question is **finite**.

Consider the group $G$ of invertible linear operators on the vector space in question. Since the space is finite-dimensional & the scalar field is finite, the vector space itself is finite, and the space of linear operators is finite. Hence $G$, being a subset of the space of all operators, is finite too. Now the result follows from [general group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893362/elements-of-finite-groups-have-finite-order): for any $P \in G$ we have $P^{|G|} = I$, the identity operator.

Answer (score 5):

I'll make a try:

Take $P,P^2,P^3,...$. Then these can't be all different because the have entries from a finite field. Then $P^t=P^s\Rightarrow P^n=I$ since $P$ is invertible